# Передача аргументов через Popen

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

Есть python скрипт, для примера:

```
while True:   
    # do something #  
    args = "C:\python\python.exe sub.py"
    process = subprocess.Popen(args)
    # do something #
```

Как передать переменную в дочерний процесс? А точнее как её принять в дочернем процессе?

Comment: Если вы именно Питон код в другом процессе хотите запустить, то multiprocessing модуль большую гибкость и удобство предоставляет: [Python открыть независимый сопроцесс (cmd)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/776232/23044)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вызывающем скрипте

```
args = ['C:\python\python.exe', 'sub.py', 'argument']
process = subprocess.Popen(args)
```

В вызываемом

```
import sys

print(sys.argv[1])
```