# Python открыть независимый сопроцесс (cmd)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

Мне нужно, чтобы я смог запустить новое окно CMD(terminal или xterm), где смог бы запуститься другой python модуль, причем, чтобы главная программа продолжила работу. Решение нужно универсальное для Windows и Linux. (скрипт для выполнения второй CMD лежит в той же директории. Parent.py - основная программа, Child.py - вторая программа).

Comment: А что если на системе, на которой будет запускаться ваш скрипт, окон вообще не будет существовать?)

Comment: В скриптах есть проверка на "совместимость", скрипт не предназначен для систем без графической оболочки

Comment: зачем вы xterm хотите запустить? Это форма GUI такая? [Opening a Python thread in a new console window](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11712629/4279)

Comment: Это не GUI просто так компактнее выводить данные чем через отдельный терминал

Comment: @stargame25 не ясно, вы хотите новое окно, отдельный терминал запустить или нет?

Comment: @jfs я хочу открыть новую командную строку, в Windows это CMD, на Linux это Terminal, но для удобности я хотел бы запустить Xterm, и в них запустить Python скрипт.

Comment: Есть вариант запуска с помощью subprocess, psutil, OS.start*, но как не экспериментировал не мог слепить нечего работающего

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> причем что бы главная программа продолжила работу.

Чтобы запустить внешнюю команду, не дожидаясь её окончания:

```
import subprocess

command = ['программа', 'первый аргумент', 'второй']
p = subprocess.Popen(command)
# ... основная программа
```

обратите внимание функции в `subprocess` модуле (в отличии от `os.system()`) не запускают shell, если вы явно не попросите, поэтому к примеру, для [внутренних команд CMD](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-internal.html) таких как `START` необходимо явно CMD запускать.

Этот вызов работает как на *nix так и на Windows.

Существует несколько градаций (спектр) "независимости" процесса (вплоть до демона/системного сервиса). См. [Запустить независимый скрипт Python из другого скрипта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/693446/23044).

---

Если вы хотите графическое окно открыть и в нём запустить команду:

```
import platform
import subprocess

# define a command that starts new terminal
if platform.system() == "Windows":
    new_window_command = "cmd.exe /c start".split()
else:  
    new_window_command = "x-terminal-emulator -e".split()

subprocess.check_call(new_window_command + command)
```

- [How can I open two consoles from a single script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19479504/4279)
- [keep multiple console windows open from batch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12122535/4279)

---

Если вы хотите Питон-код в отдельном процессе выполнить, то можно использовать [`sys.executable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.executable), чтобы тот же исполняемый файл, что и текущий Питон-интерпретатор, запустить.

Чтобы найти путь к файлу относительно текущего скрипта, [есть функции (такие как `get_script_dir()`), которые могут помочь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/535318/23044):

```
import os
import sys

command = [sys.executable, os.path.join(get_script_dir(), 'do_something.py'),
           'other', 'args']
```

Если модуль, который вы хотите запустить, находится в [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path), то можно [`-m` ключ](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m)  использовать:

```
command = [sys.executable, '-m', 'do_something', 'other', 'args']
```

Вместо запуска как независимого скрипта, вы можете импортировать соответствующий модуль и вызвать функции из него, используя [`multiprocessing` модуль](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import multiprocessing as mp
import do_something

if __name__ == '__main__':
   mp.Process(target=do_something.main, args=['other', 'args']).start()
   # ... основная программа
```

См. [Calling a python script with input within a python script using subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30076185/4279).

Answer (score 1):

Можете попробовать стандартным методом.

```
import os

os.system('x-terminal-emulator -e python test.py')
```

subprocess.Popen лучше, но не на всех системах работает почему-то

Comment: `subprocess.Popen` работает и на Windows и на POSIX системах. Если он для вас не сработал, то задайте отдельный вопрос (к примеру, вы могли команду как строку передать, а не как список на POSIX системе).

Comment: Спасибо, попробую