# Запись stderr внешней команды в локальную переменную

Tags: python, потоки-данных, subprocess

Необходимо записать поток ошибок в локальную переменную вместо файла, ожидаемый результат:

```
err = str()
with open('stdout.txt', 'w') as out:
    subprocess.check_call('python proc.py', stdout=out, stderr=err, shell=True)
```

Хочется получить `Traceback` скрипта `proc.py` в локальную строковую переменную, а не писать его в файл после чего читать оттуда и удалять файл

Comment: @MaxU, меня интересует выполнение этой задачи в контексте `check_call`, иные способы мне знакомы

Comment: https://crashcourse.housegordon.org/python-subprocess.html#error-checking

Comment: Рассмотрите другие варианты запуска Питон-кода: `import`, [multiprocessing модуль, exec(), `-m`, явный путь указывать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/778299/23044)

Answer (score 1):

```
import subprocess 

process = subprocess.run(command, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
err = process.stderr
```

где `command` к примеру:

```
command = [sys.executable, '-c', '1/0']
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте оттолкнуться от этого вот кода. Он все данные собирает в переменные, потом их можно записать/вывести куда нужно - на экран или в файл.
Недостаток в том, что, пока работает p.communicate(), аутпут особо нигде не виден

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

cmd = 'python proc.py'
p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, close_fds=True)
try:
    out, err = p.communicate()
    status = p.returncode
except Exception, e:
    out = curr_out + e.message
    err = e.message
    status = 500
return out, err, status
```

Если нужен текущий вывод по мере появления, то можно его собирать и обрабатывать построчно или порциями. Что-то в этом духе:

```
p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, close_fds=True)
curr_out = ''
done = False
while not done:
    portion = ''
    while len(portion) < 512:
        nextline = p.stdout.readline()
        if nextline == '' and p.poll() is not None:
            done = True
            break
        portion = '%s%s' % (portion, nextline)
    curr_out = '%s%s' % (curr_out, portion)
try:
    out, err = p.communicate()
    if curr_out:
        out = curr_out
    status = p.returncode
except Exception, e:
    out = curr_out + e.message
    err = e.message
    status = 500
return out, err, status
```